# Setting up an alert for Long Running Pipelines in ADF v2 using Kusto Query

Tags: azure-log-analytics

I have a pipeline in ADF V2 which generally takes 3 hours to run but some times it takes more than 3 hours. so I want to set up an alert if the pipeline running more than 3 hours using Azure log analytics (Kusto Query), I have written a query but it shows the result if the pipeline succeeded or failed. I want an alert if the pipeline taking more than 3 hours and it's in progress.

My query is

```
ADFPipelineRun
| where PipelineName == "XYZ"
| where (End - Start) > 3h
| project information = 'Expected Time : 3 Hours, Pipeline took more that 3 hours' ,PipelineName,(End - Start)
```

Could you please help me to solve this issue?

Thanks in Advance.
Lalit

Comment: what do you mean "I have written a query but it shows the result if the pipeline succeeded or failed."?

Comment: It means it throws an alert after the pipeline successful or failed. But i want an alert when the pipeline is in progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**:

Please change your query like below:

```
ADFPipelineRun 
| where PipelineName == "pipeline11"
| top 1 by TimeGenerated
| where Status in ("Queued","InProgress")
| where (now() - Start) > 3h //please change the time to 3h in your case
| project information = 'Expected Time : 3 Hours, Pipeline took more that 3 hours' ,PipelineName,(now() - Start)
```

Explanation:

The pipeline has some statuses like: `Succeeded`, `Failed`, `Queued`, `InProgress`. If the pipeline is now running and not completed, its status must be one of the two: `Queued`, `InProgress`.

So we just need to get the latest one record by using `top 1 by TimeGenerated`, then check its status if `Queued` or `InProgress`(in query, its `where Status in ("Queued","InProgress")`).

At last, we just need to check if it's running more than 3 hours by using `where (now() - Start) > 3h`.

I test it by myself, it works ok. Please let me know if you still have more issue.

Comment: Thank you Ivan, I have already set up the rule, But i want an alert if the pipeline is in progress.

Comment: @LalitKothawade, you mean if the pipeline has already completed with duration > 3h, then don't need to alert. Just list the ones is still in running state but not finished in 3h?

Comment: @LalitKothawade, I updated my answer, please take a look. And if it's helpful, please accept it as answer, as per [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top). Thanks:).

Comment: I Ivan, Yes your answer is correct for setting up an alerting system in log analytics, But i want the kusto query to find long running pipelines in adf v2 which are in progress (not succeeded or failed). My query is running fine for succeeded and failed pipeline.

Comment: @LalitKothawade, did you read my explanation in the answer in the updated section? the new query is just for the one which is running now and is taking 3 hours. please read the explanation and let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Yes This is helpful, Thanks!